# Android SQLite insert is slower than iOS

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

On Android app, the insertion of huge JSON response in to multiple table takes around 30 seconds. Where as on iOS app with same schema takes only 5 seconds. There is a table with more than 300k records. On Android, when I created a sample app with same table schema and inserted 300k records, it took 11 seconds. This is done inside the transaction block.

- Android device - Samsung M30s.
- iOS device - iPhone X.

The code I used in sample app is below.

```
MyDb myDb = new MyDb(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = myDb.getWritableDatabase();
db.enableWriteAheadLogging();
String sqltp1 = createInsert("fieldpoint", new String[]{"pointId", "definitionId", "modified", "value"}, null);
SQLiteStatement statementtp1 = db.compileStatement(sqltp1);
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
db.beginTransaction();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    statementtp1.clearBindings();
    statementtp1.bindLong(1, i);
    statementtp1.bindLong(2, i + 10);
    statementtp1.bindLong(3, 0);
    statementtp1.bindString(4, "myDbTest");
    statementtp1.execute();
}
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
myDb.close();
```

Is there any way we can reduce the db insertion time?

Comment: DB insertion depends on device Hardware. Have you tried OnePlus , Pixel or any other high end device. My app took 2 min Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro and merely 30 seconds in OnePlus to load 200K+ records.

Comment: Compare both both RAM.

Comment: @AlphaOne On Pixel 2xl for 3 lakh records it took 7 seconds.

Comment: @SAM8 it also depends on the other running processes and RAM available at that time.

Comment: @AlphaOne what is the minimum time taken for inserting 3 lakh records on the best Android device in the world. Will it be less than iPhone X in ideal conditions? Just asking is there any study happened?

Comment: @SAM8 I'm not sure about it. But there a few things to note like Android is an open source operating system, so companies like Xiaomi, Samsung, LG OnePlus etc modify it according to their brand and they add extra apps which runs in background consuming resources, on the other hand iOS is used only by apple and they have configured it such that it's work fast. I hope you are getting my point. I believe using a Stock Android ROM with high end processor like Snapdragon 845 may surpass iOS.

Comment: The batch insert, inserting multiple rows in a single statement is almost three times faster than what I had posted in questions. Example query INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES ((?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?))